# contact form 7 get field label instead of name

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

i have an simple question about **contact form 7 WP plugin**:

how can i inform about field title(label, not name property) in posted data when contact form submits?

i know my desired hook and my code is working fine, but i need **LABELS** not field names, how can i get them from cf7 is there any function or anything else?

case:
if my form be one like below:

```
    <p>label1<br />[text* your-name] </p>

    <p>label2<br />[email* your-email] </p>

    <p>label3<br />[text your-subject] </p>

    <p>label4<br />[textarea your-message] </p>

    <p>[submit "submit your idea"]</p>
```

i will receive following data in my code:

```
    your-name=>x
    your-email=>y
    your-subject=>z
    your-message=>a
```

but the question is: what is 'your-name' title in real and how can i inform about it?

thank you in advance.

Comment: your-name=>x .. received in mail ? Right ?

Comment: @MansukhKhandhar no they are accessible from posted data. i have not expected from posted data to send labels. but i want to know how to fetch them using contact form functions?